# Python Kivy using Atlas

Tags: python, button, kivy, atlas

I've started using Kivy for python app's UI. 
I want to style my buttons using an atlas with images. 
I've created one, with some standard 100x100 png images: btn_up, btn_down.

```
Button:
                text: _('State')
                font_size: 22
                on_press: screens.current = 'current_state'
                background_normal: 'atlas://res/bkts_atlas/btn_up'
                background_down: 'atlas://res/bkts_atlas/btn_down'
```

The image on the buttons is stretched.
The default Kivy button (using defaultheme atlas) is rendered ok, even if the button image is a square-like image in the atlas. I mean it keeps a nice form when rendered even if the button size isn't square.
How can I fix it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Button stretches its image disproportionately in order to let you use a single image for different button shapes (note how the default image always has borders of the same width, no matter the button size). I think the way to disable this is just to add `border: 0, 0, 0, 0`, or other options will have other effects.